# Bind same command to datagrid double click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menu item that is configured to execute a command using binding:

```
<MenuItem Margin="2" 
     Header="Process something"
     Command="{Binding SomethingCommand}" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding SomethingIsEnabled}">
</MenuItem>
```

It also configure if this item is enabled or not.

Now, I need to execute the same command when user double click a row in datagrid and only when "SomethingisEnabled" is true.

How to configure datagrid to do that?

Comment: Why have a separate `SomethingIsEnabled` property?  Why not let `SomethingCommand.CanExecute` determine whether the command is available?  If `CanExecute` returns false, the `MenuItem` will be disabled automatically.

Comment: I didn´t know that. I´ll give a try. But, what about the datagrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" in xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

This will call a relaycommand SomethingCommand and pass the selected item (if any, otherwise null) on the doubleclicked grid.

Comment: System.Windows.Interactivity, I use mvvm light (galasoft) and it might have auto-added that to my project. You can get it via nuget.